# Separate scanf input with space in C

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf, break

I try to input a series of numbers, every number separated by a space. The series of numbers has to stop taking input once a `0` is given.

I do this with a `for` loop. If I separate every number with `\n`, it stops indeed reading input after I have given `0` as a number.

But if I instead separate every number with a space, nothing happens after I give a `0`. It just keeps reading input.

I tried to find an answer, I'm sorry if the solution is obvious. I just started in C, please bear with me..

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

    int ar[1000];
    int i;

    printf("Give a series of numbers, separated by space. Stop reading when `input is 0.\n --> : ");`

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE ; i++){
        scanf("%d", &ar[i]);
        if (ar[i] == 0){break;}
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: you have to press enter to start processing that line. `scanf` does not even read the first number on a line, untill you press enter.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, scanf only initializes after you press enter? Is there no way around this? (using scanf) to make it initialize a loop with space? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: your code has a couple of compile errors, but should work with those fixed: SIZE needs to be defined somewhere (maybe you have this in a header?), and it should really match your array size; and you've got a stray apostrophe at the end of your printf line

Comment: @whizdiz see [Non buffered getc(3) under GNU/Linux](http://shtrom.ssji.net/skb/getc.html) and [normally terminal input is line buffered in the kernel](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdout.3.html#NOTES)

Comment: Is there a reason why you need it to stop reading when a 0 is entered? Why not just say in your instructions "press enter when finished"?

Comment: @pb2q SIZE has been defined in the headers. it matches my array header. I forgot to change SIZE to 1000 in this code example, for clarity. The stray apostrophe is only here, not in my actual code.

Comment: @Wimmel, thanks for the good reading material, will def check those.

Comment: @DigitalNinja I try exactly to follow the instructions of my assignments. I could use enter yes, but that would defeat the purpose of the assignment I guess, which clearly states input should stop with 0 (after separating the values with space.

Comment: To all, I code on Windows, Linux tips can be useful but are not intended as a solution for this assignment.

Answer (score 3):

By default, most command-line terminals will only send input to the running program after you finish typing a whole line. This is to give you a chance to fix typos with the backspace key.

One easy solution is to, instead of typing the input by hand, put it in a text file and use file input redirection (`<`). This input redirection syntax works on both Linux and Windows shells.

```
myProgram.exe < myInput.txt
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, might come handy later. Though now I try to follow my assignment, which clearly expects the input to be done by hand.

Comment: Making the input stop as soon as you type a 0 but before you press a newline is pretty complicated and you have to use APIs that are specific to your operating system. Are you sure both of these are requirements? Perhaps its OK to have to type a newline at the end?

Comment: Indeed, I guess I'll have to settle for newline. These are assignments after the first introductory lecture, they can't be as complicated as the solutions I find. Right now I was trying with getchar(), but yes I think buffer handling has to be addressed too, and that's very probably not what they expect me to do yet.